# in mobile, inside instagram when click bio link, the web popup closes

Tags: html, file-upload, instagram

My question is about upload form in web links inside instagram app

Situation :
• On mobile device
• inside instagram app
• when click on a weblink of a bio : it pops a web browser.

when there is a upload form, it closes without warning or error :(

How to pin point where is the error ???

• tried safari or chrome directly on same device -> same web link -> no error.

how can I debug this ? (because the "bug" happens on certain devices...)

I tested regular code

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```